# Change 'graph-theory' tag name

Tags: discussion, tags

We have a [graph-theory](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graph-theory) tag which covers puzzles involving graphs, for example:

> [Step into the Octagram](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/85499/step-into-the-octagram)

but calling it 'graph-theory' is a bit prententious for a site called 'Puzzling'.

May I suggest a new tag called simply 'Graphs', or just a name change of the existing tag.

---

**Addendum**

I've removed the 'graph-theory' tag from the questions in question.

On reflection, I agree the tag name is justified, but not for these questions, which could probably just use with the 'visual' tag.

Answer (score 9):

I'm against this change: it's unnecessary, and would be actively harmful.

"Graph theory" is the name of the field of mathematics that studies those graphs. We have [number-theory](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/number-theory) and [combinatorics](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/combinatorics) as well; both of those tags are for puzzles relating to those fields. Why should we introduce an inconsistency?

Additionally, [graphs](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphs) could be misinterpreted as "visual representations of data" rather than "sets of vertices connected by edges". [graph-theory](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graph-theory) is both unambiguous and consistent with several other tags.

Comment: There's something to be said for _distinguishing_ between questions that are actually about graph theory and questions that merely happen to have graphs in them. The octagram and heptagram puzzles are in the latter category.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan True! But that seems more to me like an argument for removing the tag from that puzzle, rather than making a new tag. (I don't think a tag for "this puzzle has a graph in it" is useful any more than, say, one for "this puzzle has a polygon in it".)

Comment: I'll concur that [tag:graphs] to indicate the presence of a graph in a puzzle is a meaningless distinction. (That's not to say we don't already have plenty of what seem to be meaningless distinctions — [tag:rhyme] and [tag:poetry] tags, lookin' at you, among others. But "graphs" here seems particularly useless and I would agree that if it causes confusion, it should be stricken from puzzles that use it just to refer to the presence of a graph of some sort.)